"error: command '/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc' failed with exit code 1" getting this error while building setup.py of bottom-up-attention.pytorch
so i am trying to extract features from images for my project using "https://github.com/MILVLG/bottom-up-attention.pytorch" and getting this error again and again.
I have successfully installed detectron2 and getting this error when trying to build setup.py of bottom-up-attention.pytorch.
I am using google colab with T4 gpu support.
Pasting the whole output below.
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/utils
copying utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/utils
copying utils/extractor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/utils
copying utils/extract_features_faster.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/utils
copying utils/extract_utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/utils
copying utils/extract_features_multigpu.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/utils
copying utils/progress_bar.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/utils
copying utils/extract_d2features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/utils
copying utils/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/utils
copying utils/extract_features_singlegpu.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/utils
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/evaluation
copying evaluation/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/evaluation
copying evaluation/vg_evaluation.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/evaluation
copying evaluation/vg_eval.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/evaluation
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua
copying bua/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua
copying bua/visual_genome.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/d2
copying bua/d2/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/d2
copying bua/d2/config.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/d2
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe
copying bua/caffe/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe
copying bua/caffe/config.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe
copying bua/caffe/postprocessing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/d2/dataloader
copying bua/d2/dataloader/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/d2/dataloader
copying bua/d2/dataloader/build_loader.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/d2/dataloader
copying bua/d2/dataloader/dataset_mapper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/d2/dataloader
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe/dataloader
copying bua/caffe/dataloader/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe/dataloader
copying bua/caffe/dataloader/transform_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe/dataloader
copying bua/caffe/dataloader/detection_utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe/dataloader
copying bua/caffe/dataloader/dataset_mapper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe/dataloader
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe/modeling
copying bua/caffe/modeling/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe/modeling
copying bua/caffe/modeling/backbone.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe/modeling
copying bua/caffe/modeling/rpn.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe/modeling
copying bua/caffe/modeling/roi_heads.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe/modeling
copying bua/caffe/modeling/rpn_outputs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe/modeling
copying bua/caffe/modeling/fast_rcnn.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe/modeling
copying bua/caffe/modeling/box_regression.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe/modeling
copying bua/caffe/modeling/rcnn.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/bua/caffe/modeling
running build_ext
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py:499: UserWarning: Attempted to use ninja as the BuildExtension backend but we could not find ninja.. Falling back to using the slow distutils backend.
  warnings.warn(msg.format('we could not find ninja.'))
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py:418: UserWarning: The detected CUDA version (12.2) has a minor version mismatch with the version that was used to compile PyTorch (12.1). Most likely this shouldn't be a problem.
  warnings.warn(CUDA_MISMATCH_WARN.format(cuda_str_version, torch.version.cuda))
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py:428: UserWarning: There are no x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ version bounds defined for CUDA version 12.2
  warnings.warn(f'There are no {compiler_name} version bounds defined for CUDA version {cuda_str_version}')
building 'bua.caffe.modeling._C' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/bottom-up-attention.pytorch
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/bottom-up-attention.pytorch/bua
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/bottom-up-attention.pytorch/bua/caffe
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/bottom-up-attention.pytorch/bua/caffe/modeling
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/bottom-up-attention.pytorch/bua/caffe/modeling/layers
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/bottom-up-attention.pytorch/bua/caffe/modeling/layers/csrc
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/bottom-up-attention.pytorch/bua/caffe/modeling/layers/csrc/nms
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py:1967: UserWarning: TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST is not set, all archs for visible cards are included for compilation. 
If this is not desired, please set os.environ['TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST'].
  warnings.warn(
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -DWITH_CUDA -I/content/bottom-up-attention.pytorch/bua/caffe/modeling/layers/csrc -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/TH -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/THC -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c /content/bottom-up-attention.pytorch/bua/caffe/modeling/layers/csrc/nms/nms.cu -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/bottom-up-attention.pytorch/bua/caffe/modeling/layers/csrc/nms/nms.o -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr --compiler-options '-fPIC' -DCUDA_HAS_FP16=1 -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE=\"_gcc\" -DPYBIND11_STDLIB=\"_libstdcpp\" -DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI=\"_cxxabi1011\" -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_C -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -gencode=arch=compute_75,code=compute_75 -gencode=arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 -std=c++17
/content/bottom-up-attention.pytorch/bua/caffe/modeling/layers/csrc/nms/nms.cu:5:10: fatal error: THC/THC.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <THC/THC.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command '/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc' failed with exit code 1 

I looked for the error in github repository of bottom-up-attention.pytorch and detectron2 but found nothing related.
